# Recharts: Turn off background hover for bar charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

Is there a way to turn off this gray background that appears on hover for bar charts in [Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US)?

[image: Screenshot of bar chart with gray background appearing behind bars.]

Using version 1.4.1. Code (simplified) looks like this:

```js
import React from "react"

// Recharts
import { Bar, BarChart, CartesianGrid, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis } from "recharts"

import CustomTooltip from "../CustomTooltip"

const BarChart = ({ chartData, chartInfo }) => (
  <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height={260}>
    <BarChart data={chartData}>
      <XAxis
        dataKey="label"
        type="category"
        allowDuplicatedCategory={true}
        tickLine={false}
        orientation="bottom"
      />

      <YAxis
        tickLine={false}
        orientation="left"
        axisLine={false}
      />

      <Tooltip
        isAnimationActive={false}
        separator={": "}
        content={<CustomTooltip />}
      />

      <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />

      {chartInfo.map(bar => (
        <Bar
          key={bar.dataKey}
          name={bar.name}
          dataKey={bar.dataKey}
          isAnimationActive={false}
        />
      ))}
    </BarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
)

export default BarChart
```

I've poured over the [API docs](http://recharts.org/en-US/api) as well as looking through the source code. Doesn't seem to be a way to do it, but some of the demos have it disabled, like [this one](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomShapeBarChart).

I tried setting up mine with custom shapes like that demo and rendering with `Cell` instead of `Bar`, but the background was still there on hover. The background color is `#ccc` but searching the repository with that keyword yielded no clear methods or props to try to override or hook into.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the `cursor` prop on the `<Tooltip />` to achieve what you need:

```
<Tooltip cursor={{fill: '#f00'}} />
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/45hwtx2c/)**'s a working fiddle I made based on some example from their docs.

You can simply use `transparent` as a value for the `fill` property.

```js
const {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];
const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
 render () {
   return (
     <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <Tooltip cursor={{fill: 'transparent'}}/>
       <Legend />
       <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
       <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/prop-types@15.6.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/recharts@1.4.2/umd/Recharts.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! I thought for sure I had tried that prior, but I guess not because I tried it just now and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Use following code to turn off the background color 
<Tooltip cursor={false} />

Comment: This should be in the documentation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 26):

The grey area you mentioned is called `cursor`. Quoting the [`Tooltip`](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#cursor) API docs:

> If set false, no cursor will be drawn when tooltip is active.

So the answer to your question is:

```
<Tooltip cursor={false} />
```

BTW, I'm using recharts@1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Use below cursor attribute to Tooltip.

```
<Tooltip cursor={{fill: 'transparent'}}/>
```